# Allow my other pages to access a dir restricted with .htaccess

Tags: php, linux, .htaccess

I have some sensitive pages which I dont want to expose to external users. So I have put them in a folder (say xyz) and restricted the access with .htaccess for entire folder.
Now lets say user have access to index.php

Is there a way for index.php to source some files from xyz and those files to remain restricted from external user.

So the structure is:

```
  html
   |
   |- index.php
   |- xyz
      |- .htaccess
      |- myfunctions.php
      |- myadminpage.php
```

Can index.php source myfunctions.php inside it?

```
   require_once 'xyz/myfunctions.php'
```

Comment: htaccess is read by the web server, not PHP. PHP can source code from anywhere on disk that it has permissions to read from. You’ll also find this is a very common pattern in modern web frameworks, however they go a step further, skip the htaccess file, and move the entire code base away from public access, and only include a single router/kernel in the web root folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can `index.php` source `myfunctions.php` inside it?
>
> ```
> require_once 'xyz/myfunctions.php'
> ```

Yes.

`.htaccess` only applies to HTTP traffic. An internal request on the server (via `require`, `include`, `fopen`, etc. <sup>***1**</sup>) bypasses `.htaccess` (except in some unusual server configs).

(<sup>***1**</sup> assuming you're not requesting the file over HTTP, ie. using [URL-wrappers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php).)